# What is a cluster health in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm new to Elastic Search, and I'm trying to figure out what does the cluster health represent. I have looked through the [references](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index.html) and [ES definitive guide](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/index.html) but I can't find the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is described in the [cluster health api page](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cluster-health.html). The status is the key piece of information to look for.

- Red = One or more primary shards are missing
- Yellow = All primary shards are allocated but replicas are not
- Green = All primary and
  replica shards have been allocated

Comment: Reusing same question,

what is the difference while checking for cluster health with wait_for_status=green vs wait_for_active_shards='all'

Does it mean the same?